# Entity Framework 6.0 Performance Issue with .AsEnumerable() with glimpse asp.net screenshot

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am trying to query the database but it is giving me performance issue during login using 
              signinmanager.passwordsigninasync()
Method takes 3 sec during initial login request.
While during fetching data from the database the query

```
    var allposts = _context.Posts
            .Where(t => t.PostAuthor.UserName == userName && t.Archived == isArchived) //.ToList();
                               .Select(e => new
                               {
                                   e,//for later projection
                                   e.Comments,//cache Comments
                                   Sender = e.Comments.Select(m => m.Sender),//cache Comments
                                   Receiver = e.Comments.Select(m => m.Receiver),//cache Comments
                                   //cache filtered Attachments
                                   Attachments = e.Attachments.Where(a => a.Owner is Teacher),
                                   e.PersonPosts,
                                   e.PostAuthor, //cache PostAuthor
                                   e.PostSfClass,

                               })
                               .AsEnumerable()
                               .Select(e => e.e).ToList();
```

takes 8 sec to get data.
glimpse screenshot for the page load from login is also attached for reference. Please help.

Comment: glimpse screensht URL http://my.jetscreenshot.com/26689/20151124-ayn7-63kb

Answer (score 0):

Don't pay attention to load times in development. The information you get from tools like Glimpse is only useful in context with other data from your site. If one page jumps up to like 30 secs to load, versus most only taking 1-10 sec, then you know there's something to look at on that page. However, debugging your site in general causes everything to load slower, and depending on the specs of your machine and how much else you've got running on that machine, it can be much slower still.

If you want meaningful statistics about page load performance, there is no substitute for publishing your site to a server that's a proxy of what you will be deploying to, including the setup of whatever database server you will be utilizing. Then, you can profile and make decisions on things that are too slow. In development, on a local machine, you can't tell anything about the site's final performance.

That said, be careful with lazy-loading. As you have it now, you should be fine, as the `Select` should be incorporated into the query and all these relationships will be joined. However, you have `.ToList` commented out before the call to `Select`. Were you call `ToList`, first, then when you get to the `Select` all of these relationships would each issue their own queries, resulting in a N+1 query scenario for each. To be safe, it's better to call `Include` for each relationship you intend to access, so that you'll know that everything will be queried at once, instead of relying on chance or order of ops to determine what happens in the query.

Comment: the issue with Include that I cannot apply the filter for Attachment as I have done in the above query. Could you please help me with the Attachment filter in Include query with an example.
Your help will be very helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you don't want to load partial classes, but this should do what you want, I htink.  Normally, I would just Include the entire Attachments collection, and only use what I need, but if the query gets too large then you have to do what you have to do.

```
allposts = _context.Posts
  .Where(t => t.PostAuthor.UserName == userName && t.Archived == isArchived)
  .Include(p=>p.Comments)
  .Include(p=>p.Comments.Select(m=>m.Sender))
  .Include(p=>p.Comments.Select(c=>c.Receiver))
  .Include(p=>p.PersonPosts)
  .Include(p=>p.PostAuthor)
  .Include(p=>p.PostSfClass);

//preload teacher attachments
allposts.SelectMany(p=>p.Attachments.Where(a=>a.Owner is Teacher)).Load();
```

Comment: This code is cleaner, and in a back to back comparison between this and the posted code, the connection time reduces significantly but the query takes twice as long.